Unable to import cv2 in Python Ubuntu environment
My Ubuntu version is :
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

I tried to install various ways and they were successful always.
$sudo apt-get install python3-opencv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-opencv is already the newest version (4.2.0+dfsg-5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 49 not upgraded.

But when I try to import, I get this result :
 import cv2, sys, numpy, os
      ImportError: No module named cv2

I don't have any clue what is wrong. I also tried to install using 'sudo pip install opencv-python', but every time I get the same result.

who told you to "import opencv as cv2"? not a rhetorical question. I'd very much like you to answer that.

now you've changed the question from a typo to something we can no longer be sure is actually accurate. did you just now actually run import cv2 and did it actually fail? nor do we know which python you started. it could have been a python 2

I have not changed the question, I made the modification in the error section, as previous error (by executing the command 'import opencv as cv2' ) caused some confusion.
I have run multiple python programs which 'import cv2' and all resulted the same error :  "ImportError: No module named cv2"
When I am writing something in this forum, obviously I tried multiple options before writing here. Anyway, as you have the authority to downgrade a question, you are doing your job, but that doesn't help much to common users.

yes you did change the question, substantially. the error message literally said ImportError: No module named opencv. and that is a simple typo/mistake and no amount of messing around with the opencv installation (as suggested in that answer below) has any chance of fixing that. do not gaslight me. everyone can read the question's history and your edit to it.

Have you tried using this solution from a bit of an older post?
The post was: Stackoverflow Post which was based on this blog from 2015. The way this post outlines on fixing the issue is by manually compiling OpenCV yourself. (By my understanding). You could also try checking the official docs to compile with that: OpenCV Docs
If this doesn't work however you could try just cloning the github repo (I know not the greatest way but it should work..)
$ sudo apt-get install git
$ git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git


bad answer. all of that isn't gonna fix OP's mistake. you can't just post a bad answer. there are always going to be people who will check you. do not copy-paste google results. do not use generative AI. you have to have competence and experience in the subject matter. -- the question is a duplicate.

In fact I tried this link : https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html
The section "Building OpenCV from source" is able to install opencv successfully in my environment.

originally you asked why import opencv failed. that's an entirely different question, and this answer didn't solve that question.

Check the question title :  "Unable to import cv2 in Python Ubuntu environment"

the code in the version that this answer had to work with was "import opencv as cv2". the title isn't code. that code is literally a typo/mistake. you did run that. the error literally said ImportError: No module named opencv and this answer does not fix that.

For your understanding I executed this command at the command line : python3 -c "import opencv as cv2", which gave me the error : "ImportError: No module named opencv"
I did this because someone suggested this is an easy way to test if opencv is working or not. Fact is in all my program I used 'import cv' which gave me "ImportError: No module named cv2". That could be the reason for your confusion. Anyway, there is no point to drag the discussion because I solved it by building OpenCV from source which matches with the above comment.
